# Does not have accessor method M2

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api, customer-account

**Getting this error:** {"message":"Property "CustomerId" does not have accessor method "getCustomerId" in class "Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface".

Customer is not exist so getting this error.

[image]

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you need to use "id" instead of "customer_Id"

Answer (score 1):

If you review the interface Magento specifies in the error message, you'll see there is indeed no `getCustomerId` accessor method. The correct accessor method is `getId`:

```
interface CustomerInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\CustomAttributesDataInterface
{

    ...

    /**
     * Get customer id
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId();
```